# express router not working with routes that include regex

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I'm new to node and unable to create a simple route which will include regex as on of the parameter

```
// student.js - route file for route /student
app.get('/student/:/^[a-z0-9-]+$/', function(req,res){
    res.send('student found');
});
```

when i hit `localhost:3000/student/student-slug` it says `Cannot GET /student/student-slug`

**two more question**

1) how to get param which is of regex, usually we can do this `var _student = res.param.student_name` but i'm unable to think for the regex

2) how to set optional param, let's say for pagination, route is like

`/list/students/` will show list of last x student but `/list/students/48` will offset that value to 48th row

this question may be duplicate but i'm unable to find answer

Comment: **[`student\/a-z0-9-]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/eF2uV8/1)**

Comment: @rock321987 not working :\

Comment: @rock321987 hi it is working, i made a type, now can you tell me how to get value of `/a-z0-9-]+` part in the url ?

Comment: actually its `student\/[a-z0-9-]+$`..I made a typo..you need to access the first capturing group

Comment: use `.*?(student\/[a-z0-9-]+$)` ..and `res.write(req.params[1])`

Answer (score 0):

You need to `encode` the uri string before pass to request and `decode` it in your route handler.

Usage is very clear:

```
encodeURIComponent(str);
```

And for decoding use:

```
decodeURIComponent(str);
```

[check the official documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

also do checkout this blog post on [escape vs encode vs encodeURIComponent](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/)